# After updating docker stopped building images

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I updated docker as i wanted to use updated docker-compose, but now I have an error

```
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)                                                         
[+] Building 0.4s (3/3) FINISHED                                                
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                       0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2.54kB                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 113B                                          0.0s
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for common.dockerhub.{companyDomain}.pl/du/almali  0.3s 
------
 > [internal] load metadata for common.dockerhub.{companyDomain}.pl/du/almalinux:8:
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)                                                         
failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: failed to do request: Head "https://common.dockerhub.{companyDomain}.pl/v2/du/almalinux/manifests/8": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I tried to reinstall my certificates as in company manual and then restart docker, but it still doesn't work. What might be the problem? Can I check which certificates docker uses?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying in Linux, remove (or moving) `~/.docker/config.json`  file, restart docker and then try again.